# Laravel vue routing

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

How can I make sure that when a user visits my site at `/administration/login` it will go to my vue.js application otherwise it keeps into the Laravel application?

Right now I've got this:

```
#404 page
Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return view('404');
})
->where(['all' => '.*']);;

# Vue
Route::any('/administration/{all}', function () {
    return view('index');
})
->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

But that's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the order of your Route definition.

The second call to Route::get should be the first one

Comment: @Jamie, if the answer provided solves your problem, you should accept the answer as the solution.